# Make C-c pass directly to term in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to make C-c pass directly to the term in Emacs (as opposed to having to type C-c C-c). I have a function defined:

(defun newterm()
  (interactive)
  (term "/bin/bash")
  (rename-uniquely)
  (term-set-escape-char ?\C-x)
  (local-unset-key ?\C-c))

This successfully sets the escape character to C-x (what I want), but I am unable to make Emacs not capture the C-c.

Maybe it's not possible to "disable" but could it be possible to set C-c to just put C-c into the terminal?

The defaults don't make any sense to me - I type C-c all the time in terminal, and the only Emacs command I ever run when I'm in a terminal is C-x b to get to a different buffer.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to rework the keymap since it uses "C-c" for many things.
But `(define-key term-raw-map [?\C-c] 'term-send-raw)` should answer your particular question.

Comment: I've tried this both putting it in my "newterm" defun and running it separately, and emacs is still capturing C-c. I also tried (define-key term-mode-map "?\C-c" 'term-interrupt-subjob)
(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c") 'term-interrupt-subjob) and these had no effect either.

Comment: Turns out, it's a very long standing (and trivial) bug in term.el.  Your newterm should work fine (even without the local-unset-key).  This will be fixed in Emacs-24.2, but in the mean time you can replace your local-unset-key with `(define-key term-raw-map [?\C-c] 'term-send-raw)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now all I need is to get M-x working, but hopefully I can figure that one out.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the variable `term-unbind-key-list`.

```
term-unbind-key-list is a variable defined in `multi-term.el'.
Its value is ("C-x" "C-h" "M-x" "C-z")
Original value was 
("C-z" "C-x" "C-c" "C-h" "C-y" "<ESC>")

Documentation:
The key list that will need to be unbind.
```

With something like this in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq term-unbind-key-list '("C-x"
                             "C-h"
                             "M-x"
                             "C-z"))
```